# Как вернуть переменной users в функции print() значение котороe она имела до призначения ей users.lower()

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
for users in current_users:
    users = users.lower()
    if users == 'admin':
        print('Hello admin, would you like see status report?')
    else:
        print(f'Hello {users}, nice to see you!')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for users in current_users:
    if users.lower() == 'admin':
        print('Hello admin, would you like see status report?')
    else:
        print(f'Hello {users}, nice to see you!')
```